# How to disable external network calls in docker compose?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, circleci

I am running a set of tests against a large legacy service that (for now) makes external network calls to other services over the internet.

The goal for this project is to mock these external services as other docker containers within the same `docker-compose` network. Some of these services are microservices run by our organization, others are third-party vendors.

We are logging external calls to identify which external endpoints are being called by this service, and mocking those calls accordingly. But because I'll be putting this in CI, and this service has many contributors in a large organization, I want to enforce that no external services are called by isolating the entire `docker-compose` network from the internet.

Short of turning off my wifi, How can I disable external calls from these services, while still allowing services in the same docker network to communicate with each other?

The options given here: https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers do not seem to be what I want.

We use CircleCI, so if there is a solution within that configuration thats fine. I just haven't found anything related to that in those docs either, and would prefer a `docker-compose` solution so I can test it locally.

Comment: That makes sense, I never thought to use multiple networks. Thank you!

Comment: I also added an answer I originally had here to the other question, which might be an option if you need to expose ports from those containers.